# Key Rotation In AES Encryption

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, aes

I am using AES to encrypt secrets, and I store both the secrets and the encryption key in a vault. However, I encounter an issue when attempting to rotate the encryption key. The challenge lies in how to efficiently re-encrypt the data already stored in the vault(with new key in because i want to rotate the key every amount of time). It's worth noting that I am implementing this within an ASP.NET application.

Comment: Why do you want to rotate the key? If an attacker is able to copy the vault, would he not both have the encrypted secrets and keys to decrypt them? And even if the attacker only got the encrypted secrets, would that be a concern?

Comment: You can't.  I would add a rotate number to the encrypted data so you can rotate the key to be consistent with the data already encrypted.

Comment: Your question is off-topic on SO as it is not a programming but a workflow question. There is an easy way to achieve your task: don't store the "encryption key" in the fault but an encrypted "encryption key". That way you change the key in the vault time by time without touching the encrypted material.

Comment: Don't rotate your keys, unless you're really talking about changing passwords.